# Dowgrading / uninstalling numpy on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pip

I have Numpy version 1.8 installed on my Ubuntu, but I need version 1.7. I didn't manage to find any way to downgrade from 1.8 to 1.7, so I decided to simply uninstall Numpy and install the older version.

The problem is, Numpy seems to be immune to my attempts at uninstalling it. I've uninstalled it in Synaptic, and also tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
```

and:

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
```

I'm still able to import Numpy in Python succesfully. How do I downgrade or get rid of it?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you should use virtualenv.  http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

In each environment you can determine what packages and what versions to use.